# Custom product type prices not indexed

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

I created a new product type and everything works except the indexing of the price. I checked the catalog_product_index_price table and all the values are NULL. This turned out to give some problems in the layered navigation (a negative value). Do i have to call a function to get my prices indexed?

*EDIT* The product type created is created in the image of a bundled product.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bundled product's price indexer are `Mage_Bundle_Model_Price_Index` and `Mage_Bundle_Model_Resource_Indexer_Price`, referenced by the config node `global/catalog/product/type/bundle/price_indexer`. The first also adds the price index to product collections for bundled products. Have you created the indexer for your current product type?

Comment: No, so should i create a custom indexer?

Comment: If you want your price to be indexed just like bundled products, you could rewrite `bundle/price_index` so it also includes your product type, or create your own indexer if the logic is different.